# call component method on action from other component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, command-pattern

What is best way to invoke method in component A when button from component B is clicked?

Both components are separated from each other.
I believe I can use some very naive implementation with actions like:

Component A sends action:

```
{action: "BUTTON_CLICKED", value: true}
```

Reducer catch action:

```
case "BUTTON_CLICKED": {
        const newState = { ...state };
        newState.clicked = true;
        return newState;
    }
```

Component B listen for props::

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (newProps) => {
    if (newProps.clicked) {
        someMethod()
    }
};
```

and reset flag:

```
someMethod = ()=>{
   dispatch({action: "BUTTON_CLICKED", value: false})
}
```

But this way is so wrong.

Any way to implement command pattern in react/redux?

thanks

Comment: why do you say this is so wrong?

Comment: Really? Why component B should know anything about any button from component A?

Comment: Well yeah redux works this way. Its a single source of truth in your app. So yeah Component B would know changes about Component A but through redux store. Code looks clean to me

Comment: I don't know your question. Please read again document from React https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

Answer (score 3):

"What is best way to invoke method in component A when button from component B is clicked?"

I'd use event bus messaging to communicate between modules. You do emit an event in one module and in other module listening for specific event.

Example: https://github.com/olahol/react-bus

Here is VueJS related article http://vuetips.com/global-event-bus, but it should give an overview about idea.

Comment: You are right, event bus is the best way to go, but I thought that redux have some implemenation of event bus.

Comment: Finally, something simple and easy to use. I really don't understand why these popular frameworks tend to be more and more complicated to use with each iteration when progress should also mean simplicity in use and fast learning curve (at least as an option when you are not trying to build optimized or complex applications).

Answer (score 3):

The approach you have laid out seems correct. Redux has this functionality built in. You can use [`store.subscribe`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html) to listen to changes.

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(this.onStoreChange);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.unsubscribe();
}

onStoreChange = () => {
  const newState = store.getState();

  // Check if target value has changed here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what you asked and trying explain is the best pattern.  You have written proper code and I don't think you need to change this.

See you are using the Redux with the help of single source of truth. So whatever you are using is the right according to my view.